# GCC compiler does not output anything in Visual Studio Code or Atom

Tags: c++

I try to compile this code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

But it outputs
[nothing in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkt2b.png)

Comment: Look at OUTPUT.

Comment: from the picture it seems you didn't compile it, just run the app that was previously compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Atom was just broken for me, had to restart my PC and Visual Studio Code started working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).